# How to make an HTML video pause playing when switching to next video in gallery

Tags: javascript, html, video, pause

I need help figuring out how to make an html video stop playing when I click on the previous/next arrow and I'm all out of ideas at this point. I have a simple video gallery that works fine except for the fact that when I select next or previous the current video will continue to play and the audios between the new video and previous video will start to overlap each other. Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Thanks

This is the code I'm using below and didn't include any of my attempts at getting the video to pause:

```
<div class="vidContainer">
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010538.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010540.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010541.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010543.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myVideos");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you just set the display none for all the other videos and not pause them before switching.

```
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myVideos");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
      slides[i].querySelector("video").pause()
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```

This should do the trick, which pauses the video element inside each myVideo instance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add an ID field to your videos that corresponds to your slide index. Maybe prefixed with some text, but in this example I'm keeping it just the number.

```
<div class="vidContainer">
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video id="1" src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010538.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video id="2" src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010540.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video id="3" src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010541.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="myVideos">
      <video id="4" src="images/Videography/Cali/P1010543.MP4" controls style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you can identify the specific video:

```
function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("myVideos");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(i).pause();
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(slideIndex-1).play();
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp